# Why does git remote -v not show the same url as my .git/config?

Tags: git, ssh, https

I am trying to switch my remote from HTTPS to SSH. First I verify that it started out as HTTPS. I run:

`$ git remote get-url origin`

result: `https://<repo>.git`

I then run `$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<repo>.git`

Then I run so set the remote URL that I want:
`$ git remote get-url origin`

and it STILL returns `https://<repo>.git`!

...however, if I run:

`git config --get remote.origin.url`

Then I get back the expected url of `git@github.com:<repo>.git`

Comment: what is you current situation of `git remote -v`? both for push and fetch.

Comment: It gives me `https://<repo>.git ` for both push and fetch.

Comment: See if `git config --get-all remote.origin.url` produces more than one line. If so, and if your Git is new enough, `git config --show-origin --get-all remote.origin.url` will show you where the extra entry comes from. You might also have a `.git/remotes/origin` file; if so, it may define a URL.

Comment: Hm, running that returns one line, with the expected result `git@github.com:<repo>.git`
meaning that I only have one config file specifying the expected remote url?

Comment: Having the same issue here. Tried everything in this post, including restarting the machine, still the same though. `git remote -v` and entry of `.git/config` file are different

Answer (score 2):

### Check git global config

Check the global git config for any [insteadOf](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) settings which automatically replace git urls with https urls.

```
git config -l

...
url.https://github.com/.insteadof=git@github.com:
url.https://.insteadof=git://
...
```

Unset those:

```
git config --global --unset-all url.https://github.com/.insteadof
git config --global --unset-all url.https://.insteadof
```

Alternatively you could use `git config --global --edit` to edit the global config in your editor (nano, vim etc) and delete the relevant sections.

Test again and hopefully it will show the same urls with both `git remote -v` and `git config --get remote.origin.url`.

I had the same problem in a VM environment which I received from a colleague, and since I hadn't realised they had added these global config settings I couldn't figure out what was going on. It seems that some people use this as a workaround in environments which block access to git urls for whatever reason.

### Confirm ssh authentication is working

Aside from checking git's config settings, it can be helpful to make sure that ssh authentication to git is working properly.

```sh
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

If it succeeds you should see a message like the following. Any sort of error suggests there's a problem with your ssh keys, ssh settings, or environment related to ssh and you should check that first.

```
Hi userName! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Comment: Great answer with a neat information and quite underrated as this problem is so rare.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing and then adding the `origin` again, if that is ok for you.

To remove origin,

```
$ git remote rm origin
```

Verify if the origin actully removed. The secondnd command should have given you a error.

```
$ git remote -v
$ git pull
```

Now add origin and verify,

```
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repository-name.git
$ git remote -v
```

Comment: I followed these steps and still got the `https://<repo>.git` afterwards.

Comment: Strange! It's silly, but you may try restarting either of your `git daemon` or your machine.  :)